# Преобразовать файл в строку с битов

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, вывод, byte

Как преобразовать любой файл в строку, в которой файл будет представлен в бинарном виде?

Допустим, есть файл "test.txt", и мне нужно получить его в бинарном виде, что-то вроде `001011100010101100001010...`. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: любой файл и так в бинарном виде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifstream in("test.txt");
for(unsigned char c;in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&c),1);)
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        cout << (c&1), c >> 1;
```

Сойдет?

Comment: Да, спасибо, а можно еще показать обратный процесс?

Comment: Как мёд - так ложкой? :) собирайте по 8 бит в байт и записывайте этот байт в файл. Если не будет получаться что-то конкретное - тогда пишите (с вашим кодом).